# Not able to send data to remote TCP port using Socket programming in Perl

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp

My Procedure:  i am opening a file "output.txt , readin gits last line which will have the String "PASS" or "FAIL" , if PASS if found then i want to send string "OK" to server else i have to send string "ERROR"

Issue Observed: I am not able to recieve anything on Remote Server(IP 10.5.62.1) but if try using Localhost (IP 127.0.0.1) , i am able receive the string from the client. Please help to receive the string on the remote server.

I am getting the following error

> :send: Cannot determine peer address at C:\client.pl line 44
> IO::Socket::send('IO::Socket::INET=GLOB(0x31cc20)', 'ERROR') called at
> C:\client.pl line 44
>
> client code :

```
#standard includes
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use IO::File;
use English;

#local variables
my $Socket;

#Create Socket for a specified port number
$Socket = new IO::Socket::INET ( 
                   PeerAddr => '10.5.62.1',
                               PeerPort => '4754', 
                               Proto => 'tcp', 
                               Listen => 1,
                               );
                   die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $Socket;

#open the file which is required , mapping file to INPUT Macro
open INPUT, "<output.txt";
#Reading all lines from a file and storing in @lines array
my @lines = <INPUT>;
close INPUT;
#Now @lines holds all the lines, one line in each element.
print "Last line is:\n";
#checking the last line in the file as it will have the verdict "Pass" or "Fail"
print $lines[-1];
if($lines[-1]=~ 'Pass')
{
  print "Setting verdict PASS and sending OK";
 #Sending Ok to Server on Ping Success
#  print $Socket "\r\nOK\r\n"; 
$Socket->send("\r\nOK\r\n");
  }
else 
  {
   print "Setting verdict FAIL and sending ERROR";
#Sending ERROR to Server on failure  
#  print $Socket "\r\nERROR\r\n";
$Socket->send("ERROR");
 }
 #Now closing the socket as my job is done  
close($Socket);
```

> Server Code:

```
    use IO::Socket;
 

my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
                                  LocalHost => '10.5.62.1',
                                  LocalPort => '4754',
                                  Proto => 'tcp',
                                  Listen => 1,
                                  Reuse => 1,
                                 );
die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $sock;
my $new_sock = $sock->accept();
       while(<$new_sock>) {
          print $_;
       }
      close($sock);
```

Comment: Your code does not make much sense: Your client code is using "Listen" (twice), even if it not a server, your client connects to 10.5.62.1 but the server is listening at 10.5.62.3. Also, the indentation is completly messed up so it is hard to read your code. Please fix these issues and try again.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : Thanks for the feedback , i have edited the code now . I hope its logical now  :)

Comment: Please remove the 'Listen' on the client side and try again, the client should not listen, it should connect.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : i have tried removing listen from client side , but still the same issue .... please help.

Comment: Works for me if the Listen is removed. You need to start the server first, then you can run the client once (this is how your code is done). If you still have problems please fix the code in your question to exactly reflect what you use, use strict+warnings also in the server and show the exact error message, e.g. the lines in the error message reflecting the lines in the shown code.